# Parallelize behavior

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to understand some quirks of the Parallelize[] behavior.

If I do:

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[1]
f[n_, g_] := 
  First@AbsoluteTiming[
    g[Product[Mod[i, 2], {i, 1, n/2}]
      Product[Mod[i, 2], {i, n/2 + 1, n}]]];
Clear[a, b];
a = Table[f[i, Identity], {i, 100000, 1500000, 100000}];
LaunchKernels[1]
b = Table[f[i, Parallelize], {i, 100000, 1500000, 100000}];
ListLinePlot[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

The result is the expected one: 
[image]
CPU utilization:

[image]

But if I do the same, changing the function to evaluate:

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[1]
f[n_, g_] := 
  First@AbsoluteTiming[
    g[Product[Sin@i, {i, 1, n/2}] 
      Product[Sin@i, {i, n/2 + 1, n}]]];
Clear[a, b];
a = Table[f[i, Identity], {i, 1000, 15000, 1000}];
LaunchKernels[1]
b = Table[f[i, Parallelize], {i, 1000, 15000, 1000}];
ListLinePlot[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

The result is:
[image]

CPU utilization:
[image]

I think I am missing some important knowledge about Parallelize[] to understand this.

Any hints?

Comment: Might be cache misses or something similar?

Comment: as your original info page said you are a former physicist, I must ask: axes labels?  units? burying `AbsoluteTiming` in `f` is initially confusing.

Comment: @rcollyer Time units are not meaningful for the problem, as they are machine dependent. As for the labels, you may read from the previous code I am plotting AbsoluteTime[] Vs a non dimensional number linearly related to the number of iterations. BTW, I never stated I was a _good_ physicist :D

Comment: The second graph has two virtually identical curves om my quadcore laptop.

Comment: I don't think it is cache related, but "something similar" is a little too broad .. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is not in `Parallelize`, but in what you are trying to compute. For `Mod`, the result is always either 1 or 0 and the product as well. For `Sin`, since you use the integer arithmetic, you accumulate huge symbolic expressions (products of `Sin[i]`). They are discarded after having been computed, but they need the heap space (memory allocation/deallocation). The quadratic behavior you observe is likely due to the linear complexity of large size memory allocation, "multiplied" by the liner complexity from your iteration. This seems the dominant effect, which shadows the real costs of `Parallelize`. If you apply `N`, like `Sin@N[i]`, the results are quite different.

Comment: You beat me to it. Don't you have better things to do than hanging around here?  ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd You wouldn't believe :)  This time I was out all day, just came in and accidentally saw the question - was about to switch off the PC  :)

Answer (score 5):

To understand what is going on behind the scenes when using `Parallelize`, it's a good idea to enable the Parallel Computing Toolkit's debugging mode, i.e.:

```
Needs["Parallel`Debug`"]
SetOptions[$Parallel, Tracers -> {SendReceive}]
```

The second example produces a lot of MathLink communication overhead, because the Sin function applied to an integer number is not immediately evaluated by Mathematica (as Leonid Shifrin already mentioned):

Here's a portion of the debugging output:

```
SendReceive: Receiving from kernel 13: Subscript[iid, 105][Sin[1] Sin[2] Sin[3] Sin[4] Sin[5] Sin[6] Sin[7] Sin[8] Sin[9] Sin[10] Sin[11] Sin[12] Sin[13] Sin[14] Sin[15] Sin[16] Sin[17] Sin[18] Sin[19] Sin[20] Sin[21] Sin[22] Sin[23] Sin[24] Sin[25] Sin[26] Sin[27] Sin[28] Sin[29] Sin[30] Sin[31] Sin[32] Sin[33] Sin[34] Sin[35] Sin[36] Sin[37] Sin[38] Sin[39] Sin[40] Sin[41] Sin[42] Sin[43] Sin[44] Sin[45] Sin[46] Sin[47] Sin[48] Sin[49] Sin[50] Sin[51] Sin[52] Sin[53] Sin[54] Sin[55] Sin[56] Sin[57] Sin[58] Sin[59] Sin[60] Sin[61] Sin[62] Sin[63] Sin[64] Sin[65] Sin[66] Sin[67] Sin[68] Sin[69] Sin[70] Sin[71] Sin[72] Sin[73] Sin[74] Sin[75] Sin[76] Sin[77] Sin[78] Sin[79] Sin[80] Sin[81] Sin[82] Sin[83] Sin[84] Sin[85] Sin[86] Sin[87] Sin[88] Sin[89] Sin[90] Sin[91] Sin[92] Sin[93] Sin[94] Sin[95] Sin[96] Sin[97] Sin[98] Sin[99] Sin[100] Sin[101] Sin[102] Sin[103] Sin[104] Sin[105] Sin[106] Sin[107] Sin[108] Sin[109] Sin[110] Sin[111] Sin[112] Sin[113] Sin[114] Sin[115] Sin[116] Sin[117] Sin[118] Sin[119] Sin[120] Sin[121] Sin[122] Sin[123] Sin[124] Sin[125] Sin[126] Sin[127] Sin[128] Sin[129] Sin[130] Sin[131] Sin[132] Sin[133] Sin[134] Sin[135] Sin[136] Sin[137] Sin[138] Sin[139] Sin[140] Sin[141] Sin[142] Sin[143] Sin[144] Sin[145] Sin[146] Sin[147] Sin[148] Sin[149] Sin[150] Sin[151] Sin[152] Sin[153] Sin[154] Sin[155] Sin[156] Sin[157] Sin[158] Sin[159] Sin[160] Sin[161] Sin[162] Sin[163] Sin[164] Sin[165] Sin[166] Sin[167] Sin[168] Sin[169] Sin[170] Sin[171] Sin[172] Sin[173] Sin[174] Sin[175] Sin[176] Sin[177] Sin[178] Sin[179] Sin[180] Sin[181] Sin[182] Sin[183] Sin[184] Sin[185] Sin[186] Sin[187] Sin[188] Sin[189] Sin[190] Sin[191] Sin[192] Sin[193] Sin[194] Sin[195] Sin[196] Sin[197] Sin[198] Sin[199] Sin[200] Sin[201] Sin[202] Sin[203] Sin[204] Sin[205] Sin[206] Sin[207] Sin[208] Sin[209] Sin[210] Sin[211] Sin[212] Sin[213] Sin[214] Sin[215] Sin[216] Sin[217] Sin[218] Sin[219] Sin[220] Sin[221] Sin[222] Sin[223] Sin[224] Sin[225] Sin[226] Sin[227] Sin[228] Sin[229] Sin[230] Sin[231] Sin[232] Sin[233] Sin[234] Sin[235] Sin[236] Sin[237] Sin[238] Sin[239] Sin[240] Sin[241] Sin[242] Sin[243] Sin[244] Sin[245] Sin[246] Sin[247] Sin[248] Sin[249] Sin[250] Sin[251] Sin[252] Sin[253] Sin[254] Sin[255] Sin[256] Sin[257] Sin[258] Sin[259] Sin[260] Sin[261] Sin[262] Sin[263] Sin[264] Sin[265] Sin[266] Sin[267] Sin[268] Sin[269] Sin[270] Sin[271] Sin[272] Sin[273] Sin[274] Sin[275] Sin[276] Sin[277] Sin[278] Sin[279] Sin[280] Sin[281] Sin[282] Sin[283] Sin[284] Sin[285] Sin[286] Sin[287] Sin[288] Sin[289] Sin[290] Sin[291] Sin[292] Sin[293] Sin[294] Sin[295] Sin[296] Sin[297] Sin[298] Sin[299] Sin[300] Sin[301] Sin[302] Sin[303] Sin[304] Sin[305] Sin[306] Sin[307] Sin[308] Sin[309] Sin[310] Sin[311] Sin[312] Sin[313] Sin[314] Sin[315] Sin[316] Sin[317] Sin[318] Sin[319] Sin[320] Sin[321] Sin[322] Sin[323] Sin[324] Sin[325] Sin[326] Sin[327] Sin[328] Sin[329] Sin[330] Sin[331] Sin[332] Sin[333] Sin[334] Sin[335] Sin[336] Sin[337] Sin[338] Sin[339] Sin[340] Sin[341] Sin[342] Sin[343] Sin[344] Sin[345] Sin[346] Sin[347] Sin[348] Sin[349] Sin[350] Sin[351] Sin[352] Sin[353] Sin[354] Sin[355] Sin[356] Sin[357] Sin[358] Sin[359] Sin[360] Sin[361] Sin[362] Sin[363] Sin[364] Sin[365] Sin[366] Sin[367] Sin[368] Sin[369] Sin[370] Sin[371] Sin[372] Sin[373] Sin[374] Sin[375] Sin[376] Sin[377] Sin[378] Sin[379] Sin[380] Sin[381] Sin[382] Sin[383] Sin[384] Sin[385] Sin[386] Sin[387] Sin[388] Sin[389] Sin[390] Sin[391] Sin[392] Sin[393] Sin[394] Sin[395] Sin[396] Sin[397] Sin[398] Sin[399] Sin[400] Sin[401] Sin[402] Sin[403] Sin[404] Sin[405] Sin[406] Sin[407] Sin[408] Sin[409] Sin[410] Sin[411] Sin[412] Sin[413] Sin[414] Sin[415] Sin[416] Sin[417] Sin[418] Sin[419] Sin[420] Sin[421] Sin[422] Sin[423] Sin[424] Sin[425] Sin[426] Sin[427] Sin[428] Sin[429] Sin[430] Sin[431] Sin[432] Sin[433] Sin[434] Sin[435] Sin[436] Sin[437] Sin[438] Sin[439] Sin[440] Sin[441] Sin[442] Sin[443] Sin[444] Sin[445] Sin[446] Sin[447] Sin[448] Sin[449] Sin[450] Sin[451] Sin[452] Sin[453] Sin[454] Sin[455] Sin[456] Sin[457] Sin[458] Sin[459] Sin[460] Sin[461] Sin[462] Sin[463] Sin[464] Sin[465] Sin[466] Sin[467] Sin[468] Sin[469] Sin[470] Sin[471] Sin[472] Sin[473] Sin[474] Sin[475] Sin[476] Sin[477] Sin[478] Sin[479] Sin[480] Sin[481] Sin[482] Sin[483] Sin[484] Sin[485] Sin[486] Sin[487] Sin[488] Sin[489] Sin[490] Sin[491] Sin[492] Sin[493] Sin[494] Sin[495] Sin[496] Sin[497] Sin[498] Sin[499] Sin[500]] (q=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this version and I'm sure you will know what's going on.

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[1]
f[n_, g_] := 
  First@AbsoluteTiming[
    g[Product[Sin@i, {i, 1, n/2}] Product[Sin@i, {i, n/2 + 1, n}]]];
Clear[a, b];
a = Table[f[i, Identity], {i, 1000, 15000, 1000}];
LaunchKernels[1]
b1 = Table[f[i, Parallelize], {i, 1000, 15000, 1000}];
b2 = Table[f[i, Parallelize], {i, 1000., 15000., 1000.}];
ListLinePlot[{a, b1, b2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

Comment: @Sojerd Nice and clarifying example. Sorry, I can't accept both answers :(